# Issue with footer in webpage when set the position

Tags: css, html, footer

i want make a footer with relative position but when the page have not content its show on the bottom of page. a property like this:

```
position:relative absolute; [i know this isnt correct]
```

**relative** is good but when the page is not empty.

**fixed** covering some of content and show always

**absolute** not good when the page have content

this is my code:

```
color:#444;
background:#222;
bottom:0px;
width:100%;
position:relative;
min-height:80px;
padding:10px 0 10px 10px;
border-top:1px solid #444;
```

---

[image]

Comment: Can't really offer any advice, as there isn't any code to work off and your question is unclear, but it sounds like you're after a sticky footer http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/

Comment: what u really want, can u please elaborate..

Answer (score 0):

your question is unclear,but as I undrestand you want to have a footer on bottom of the page even if there is no content,do so :

```
#footer{
position:fixed;
bottom:0;
z-index:999
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tMJFF/10/)

but this way you have sticky footer to bottom of your browser window, another way to achieve what you want is tu use `min-height` css property for your content,bud this is not a fully solution,couse different browser have different height and you have problem, I suggest that you use jQuery

Comment: As far as I got OP's question, OP needs footer which can should stick to bottom if page is not long enough to cover whole viewport or else it should act normal.

Answer (score 0):

use `min-height` for content (middle content).
for example:

```
min-height: 500px;
```